# how would an iron encapsulated electromagnet work?

Tags: electromagnetism

I have been searching for this for a while now, but,

a normal electromagnet works with(example) an iron cylinder and a copper coil around it, but would it work the same if you were to encapsulate it into an iron cylinder.

If you still can't get you head around it, here is what I mean:
[image]

Would these two work differently?

Comment: Work as what? Will there be a field on the inside? Yes. Will there be much of a field outside? Probably not much, since you have made a somewhat efficient, but not ideal, magnetic return path. In optimized form this is somewhat useful for certain types of particle detectors, but probably not for what you want. If you want to get a realistic answer, you can model any geometry you like with magnetostatics software.

Comment: @CuriousOne I was referring to the magnetic field, and its strength, and what is this software called, and by who?

Comment: The question is where do you want the strongest field? Inside the coil or on the outside? FEMM (http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage) is probably the easiest to use tool, but it's only 2.5d, so you can't model every geometry, but you could model something close to what you have there. Look at the "Related Links" page.

Comment: @CuriousOne outside the encapsulation, and thank you I think this might help a lot in my projects

Comment: If you are trying to build something like lifting magnets, then I suggest you look at some cross sections like this: http://www.rfcafe.com/references/Electricity-Basic-Navy-Training-Courses/images/electricity-navy-basics-103.jpg or this one: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Lifting_electromagnet_cross_section.png. Basic recipe: Short and with an efficient magnetic return path.